# Fatal error: Call to undefined function Â mysqli_num_rows()

Tags: php

I try to count the number of rows in my query, but I get the error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Â mysqli_num_rows() in

My code is:

```
$query2 = "SELECT `vraag` FROM `log` WHERE `nam` = '3' AND `status` = '0' LIMIT 1"; 
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die("could not perform query");
$record2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
$aantal = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
```

Does anybody know what is wrong in this code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which php version are you using?

Comment: The `Â` looks like a mis-encoded UTF-8 character. Could it be that you have a stray UTF-8 space or hidden character in the code that PHP is interpreting as part of the function name? That would certainly explain it. This kind of thing can happen if you copy+paste code from other sources like web pages. Try editing the code -- delete the function name and the characters around it, and re-type them.

Comment: I agree the Â character is a little bit mysterious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to retrieve the row count in this way

```
$aantal  = $sql2->num_rows;
```

see PHP documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. There is no solution in procedural style?

Comment: theoretically it should work also using mysqli_num_rows... but it could be related to the PHP version